# Elasticsearch NEST search query is only numbers

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an issue when searching in ElasticSearch and the query is only numbers.
The code I use is

```
 var result = await _elasticClient
                .SearchAsync<MyDocument>(search =>
                    search.Index("index")
                    .From(offset)
                    .Size(size)
                    .Query(q =>
                        q.Bool(b => b
                           .Should(should => should
                               .MultiMatch(mm =>
                                    mm.Query(query)
                                   .Fields(f => f
                                       .Field("stringNumber", boost: 3)
                                       .Field("a", boost: 2)
                                       .Field("b", boost: 1)
                                   ).Lenient(true)
                                )
                           )             
                          .Should(should => should
                               .MultiMatch(mm =>
                                    mm.Query(query)
                                   .Fields(f => f
                                       .Field("a", boost: 2)
                                   ).Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Ratio(1)
                                )
                           )                            
                        )
                    )
                );
```

This gives me an empty result but when I enter kibana and put something similar I get a result.
Here is the query in Kibana

```
"size": 20, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {"multi_match": {
          "query": "1234",
          "fields": ["stringNumber", "a^2", "b^1"]
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
```

I hope someone can see my error. The C# code gives empty but the Kibana give a result of documents.

**UPDATE Fix**

```
 var result = await _elasticClient
                .SearchAsync<MyDocument>(search =>
                    search.Index("index")
                    .From(offset)
                    .Size(size)
                    .Query(q =>
                        q.Bool(b => b
                           .Should(should => should
                               .MultiMatch(mm =>
                                    mm.Query(query)
                                   .Fields(f => f
                                       .Field("stringNumber", boost: 3)
                                       .Field("a", boost: 2)
                                       .Field("b", boost: 1)
                                   ).Lenient(true)
                                )
                           ,             
                          should2 => should2
                               .MultiMatch(mm =>
                                    mm.Query(query)
                                   .Fields(f => f
                                       .Field("a", boost: 2)
                                   ).Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Ratio(1)
                                )
                           )                            
                        )
                    )
                );
```

Comment: Enable debug mode on your elasticClient and check `result.DebugInformation` after executing your query. It will show the query that was generated and executed.

Comment: Thanks that's really good to know!

Comment: Okay, I didn't give my complete code. I update the Question with lessons learned!

Answer (score 0):

Answer was found with the help of Debug and fix is in question.